# What happens to lingering sockets when the kernel reboots?

Tags: c, sockets, so-linger

I'm trying to understand what the typical behavior for the following scenario. Please note I'm open to finding out more about this edge case for any OS (*nix, Windows, ...).

If an application is blocked waiting or a lingering socket to close, what happens when the machine is rebooted?

Consider the following example scenario:

1. An application has an established TCP socket, and then calls close() on the socket. The socket is configured to linger (SO_LINGER) for say, 10 seconds.
2. Due to the linger setting, the application blocks, waiting for (up to) the 10 second linger time to TX/RX/ACK remaining data on the connection.
3. During this time, the kernel is rebooted (e.g. user reboots the machine).

What does the kernel do in such a case?

Does it force the socket to close ("abortive close")? Causing any unsent/un-ACK'd data to be lost?

Or does it respect the linger time and wait for the (possibly) full 10 seconds? (Thus blocking the reboot, possibly until the full 10 second linger time has expired).

Something else?

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: The socket ceases to exist. Incoming frames will cause ICMP to kick in, so the other side will notice.

Comment: It very much depends on your OS.

Comment: In short: you can talk to a dead person, but he wont talk back. Besides: the *fresh* kernel does not have the connection endpoints (in the correct state). And there is always th sequence nunbers.

Comment: @n.m. Right. I'm trying to understand how this is handled typically across different OSes. Basically, looking for any insights that anyone might have on this, for any OS.

Comment: @wildplasser Thank you. Yes, once the kernel actually shuts down, the socket will cease to exist. But, I'm looking into the time just before the kernel actually shuts down.  Will the kernel perform an "abortive close" on the lingering socket? Or does it wait for the linger time to expire?

Comment: It'll be more like an abortive close; it won't wait.  It is under instruction to atop; it will stop.

Comment: Normally the kernel cares not for silly applications. It's the task of the init system to bring them down.

Comment: Remember: the entire TCP layer is based on "good enough", which works ... until it doesn't. If you want real reliability, you *must* use crypto.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is for Linux, although I imagine Windows services are the same.

It depends on how the machine is rebooted. If it goes through the normal shutdown process, the TCP sockets will act the same as they do if the application is shut down normally. Because that is what happens.

If the application does not shut down within the init system's timeout, it will be killed with SIGKILL and simply stop running. Data already written to the socket's kernel buffer will be sent as if SO_LINGER was not set. Anything that wasn't buffered is lost.

Once the init system gets done it will actually reboot the machine with the `reboot` system call. See `man 2 reboot`. This immediately reboots the machine. It does not even wait for a disk sync. It certainly won't wait for TCP sockets. You can get this effect from the command line with `reboot -n -f`. Any data in the kernel's TCP socket buffers is lost.

Comment: Anything that *was* buffered may be lost too, if it doesn't get sent before the reboot.

Comment: @EJP: Yes. See last sentence. :)

Comment: @ZanLynx Thank You very much for your answer, I think this pretty much clears it up.

Comment: Thank You all for helping out on this! Your answers are very much appreciated.